# SQLite records not saved in the order they are created with Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

While inspecting the sqlite database resulting from the code below I discovered that Core Data does not seem to save the objects (records) in the order that they are created.

```
-(void) CreateData
{
// Create an organization

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *org_entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Organization" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *organization = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[org_entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[organization setValue:@"MyCompany" forKey:@"name"];
[organization setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[organization hash]] forKey:@"id"];


// Create several people

NSEntityDescription *person_entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *john = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[person_entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[john setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[john hash]]  forKey:@"id"];
[john setValue:@"John" forKey:@"name"];


NSManagedObject *jane = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[person_entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[jane setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[jane hash]]  forKey:@"id"];
[jane setValue:@"Jane" forKey:@"name"];


NSManagedObject *bill = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[person_entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[bill setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[bill hash]]  forKey:@"id"];
[bill setValue:@"Bill" forKey:@"name"];


// Designate the leader for "My Company"

[organization setValue:john forKey:@"leader"];


// Designate subordinates

NSMutableSet *johns_employees = [john mutableSetValueForKey:@"employee"];
[johns_employees addObject:jane];
[johns_employees addObject:bill];


NSError *error = nil;
if(![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
}
```

While I don't intend to rely on the order of the records for the real application it was interesting to learn that the order seems to be random.  One would think that the underlying serialization routine would produce the same results every time.

Out of curiosity, why does this happen?

Comment: Not sure about CoreData/Sqlite internals but in many databases the storage order is determined by the clustered index.  The primary key is typically the cluster index.  Without a primary key or clustered index, the order can be in the order it happens to store it and then the app needs to query and order by what's important.  If there's a clustered index and the query does not have an orderby, it comes back ordered by the clustered index.

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting sentence :

> 'One would think that the underlying serialization routine would produce the same results every time'

CoreData abstracts away the underlying storage - it can be plist, xml, sqlite etc. You can't assume anything about the underlying routines, you don't know them :) They are determined by the type of storage that whoever created the NSPersistentStore (that your NSManagedObjectContext is connected to) asked for.

If you want to get the results back in a specific order, you need to give an `NSOrderDescription` to your `NSFetchRequest` ;)

PS @bryanmac's comment is very useful in knowing why sqlite might not return results in the right order.

Comment: This is an especially strange assumption as most every flavor of SQL includes a disclaimer like "result return order is not guaranteed unless sorting is performed."

Comment: If you look at my post I do disclaim that I have no intent in trusting the stored order in real applications.  The implication here is that, yes, I will have NSFetchRequest order as needed.  But that's not the point of the post.  I am creating the database and stuffing it with data in the sequence shown.  I then inspect the database with something like SQLite Database Browser.  Nearly every time I run the code the order of the records is different.  In between runs I delete the ".sqlite" file.  It is created and stuffed from scratch every single time.  However, the results are not consistent.

Comment: This isn't a problem.  I am just trying to understand why or how it happens.

Comment: Then @bryanmac' comment on your question is a pretty good explanation - basically, if you don't specify then it's the underlying storage's choice - not only will this change with different storage types (i.e sql, xml etc) but possible even with different versions of sqllite. Without knowing exactly how sqlite works (and which version of sqlite CoreData has chosen to use, which might be different on different versions of iOS) you can't know :) Bluntly, there are much better ways of spending your time!